# Any two faces of the standard simplex are "homotopic"?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

It's intuitively clear that any two faces of the standard simplex are homotopic, more formally, for any $0\le i<j\le n$, there should be a (surjective) map in the category of simplicial sets,

> $h:\Delta^{n-1}\times\Delta^{1}\rightarrow\Delta^{n}$ such that $h\circ (1\times d^1)=d^i, h\circ (1\times d^0)=d^j$. This map should fix the intersection of the i- and j-faces, which is a $\Delta^{n-2}$.

Here $1\times d^s: \Delta^{n-1}\cong\Delta^{n-1}\times\Delta^{0}\rightarrow\Delta^{n-1}\times\Delta^{1}, s=0, 1$ are the inclusions of the endpoints of the standard 1-simplex; and the maps $d^i, d^j:\Delta^{n-1}\rightarrow\Delta^{n}$ are also the coface maps.

Drawing a picture, I think $\Delta^{n}$ should be a quotient of the prism $\Delta^{n-1}\times\Delta^{1}$, possibly by collapsing some non-degenerate n-simplices except only one of them, to a point, but I can't make this intuition rigorous. Could you make this precise?

In fact, I want to define a notion of path components of a Kan complex. In the literature, I only find the definition of $\pi_0$, which only involves the 0-simplices. I want to define path components of a Kan complex, all of which should then also be a (connected) Kan complex. If you can make sense of this without proving the above result, it would also be very helpful.

Comment: Let $x \in \pi_0(X)$ which I view as a subset of $X_0$. Then the "path component" of $x$ is the simplicial set given in dimension $n$ by the set of simplices $\sigma \in X_n$ such that $(d_0)^n(\sigma) \in x$.

Comment: Yes, I think this should be the case, but to show it's indeed a simplicial set, then what I want in the above is sufficient, without which, I can't prove what you define is stable under the simplicial operations. It will be helpful if you give more details.

Comment: A path component is a maximal connected subcomplex. It is determined by the 0-simplices it contains

Comment: Also, if you have $x \in \pi_0X$ it is probably easier to define its corresponding simplicial subset that whose $n$-simplices are the $n$-simplices all whose vertices are in $x$ (the vertices of an $n$-simplex are its restrictions along all the maps $[0]\to [n]$ in $\Delta$)

Comment: Finally (then I'll stop) to answer your main question, what about the unique map of posets satisfying your requirement on the vertices?

Comment: @ Denis Nardin Thanks a lot! I also thought about the method you said but stuck at some point (for stupid reasons). And for my main question, in general, a map on the vertices doesn't determine a map of simplicial sets. But in this particularly simple case, the map you are saying should indeed determine one. I will try to write it formally.